# Unity: how to add a shell-script to the dock

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-unity

I have a GUI application which starts with a shell script. How can I create an icon in the Unity dock by providing the shell script and an `.svg` icon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to make a shortcut-file. Shortcuts for the Unity dock are located in `~/.local/share/applications/`

1. Create a file myGUIapp.desktop in that directory.
2. Paste the following into that file (with correct paths for icon and shellscript):

   > [Desktop Entry]
   >  Name=My GUI App
   >   Exec=/path/to/shellscript.sh
   >  Icon=/path/to/you/icon.svg
   >  Terminal=false
   >   Type=Application
   >  StartupNotify=true
3. Make the file executable:

   Right click -> Properties -> Permissions -> Tick ‘Allow executing as a program’
4. Restart Unity *(or drag the file to the Dock to get it there directly)*.

Look in other files in `~/.local/share/applications/` to get an idea of how they should look. More info is available in [this blog entry](http://themagicofscience.blogspot.com/2011/05/unity-adding-items-to-dock.html).

**Edit:**
 If you want the shortcut to be accessable to all users you should check out [Ubuntu packaging guide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PackagingGuide/Complete#A.desktop_Files) about icons. 
Basically the .desktop-file are installed or moved to `/usr/share/applications/<binary>.desktop` instead and icons are placed in `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/scalable/apps`

Comment: So my application should provide this file and the user should drag it to the Dock? Does the file allows to use relative paths for exec and icon?

Comment: Ah, I didn't catch that you were making an application for others to use. I have updated my answer to include that.

Comment: Is there not a simple GUI app that can edit the Unity menu yet?

Comment: Yes there is! [Quicklist Editor](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/quicklist-editor-for-unity-launcher.html) for Unity. It's not that stable yet.